# Delphi Xe7 Android: How to show VK even though there's a physical keyboard plugged in

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard

Clearly, the underlying FMX library already does this, as it "knows" when to show the virtual keyboard and when to hide it.

My problem is that I am plugging an RFID tag reader (an OTG device) into the Android, and the Android is "seeing" it as a physical keyboard. This means the virtual keyboard never appears once the RFID tag reader has been plugged in!

What I do then is set

```
VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Never; // inside project.dpr
```

Then in

```
TfrmMain.TEdit1CanFocus(Sender: TObject; var ACanFocus: Boolean);
begin
  ShowVirtualKeyBoard(TfmxObject(Sender));
end;
```

This is great, the VK shows when the Edit1 receives focus. But now, how do I hide the keyboard when it's no longer needed?

If I use `Edit1OnExit`, the VK hides just after the VK shows (because showing the keyboard actually takes focus away from the edit).

```
procedure TfrmMain.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HideVirtualKeyBoard;
end;
```

Ultimately, the solution would be to have one more `VKAutoShowMode` option:

```
VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Anyways;
```

But I can't wait until someone decides to attend to this (Android 6.0?)

Does anyone have a better idea of how I can achieve VK automation even though there's a physical keyboard plugged in?

```
procedure ShowVirtualKeyboard(Control: TFmxObject);
var
  FService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, IInterface(FService));
  if (FService <> nil) then
  begin
    if not (TVirtualKeyBoardState.Visible in FService.VirtualKeyBoardState) then
      FService.ShowVirtualKeyboard(Control);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Does this happen only in Firemonkey apps? Or does it happen in all the apps?

Comment: There is no virtual keyboard in VCL apps. The problem is specific to FMX on Android... and after some investigation, I really ought to withdraw the question: the task simply cannot be done. The problem is at the hardware/OS level. If you have a plug-able keyboard (or an RFID reader that the device recognises as a keyboard), the VK simple doesn't show even if you instruct it to do so.

Comment: I wasn't asking about VCL, I was asking about other apps on your Android device.

Comment: I wouldn't withdraw the question - it's useful for other people to know whether or not it can't be done.  Nobody's downvoted or voted to close.

Comment: @JerryDodge Now that I understand your question, the answer is: Yes, it happens with all apps. When the RFID reader is plugged into the micro-usb port, the Android thinks the RFID reader IS a hardware keyboard, and the VK doesn't show. However, if I unplug the RFID reader, the VK shows immediately and vice-verse. So while this is inconvenient for the user (pluggin/unplugging), it's still usable. I have ordered a USB powered OTG HUB to see if that is going to make a difference. Thanks.

Comment: I have just checked, if I plug or unplug the RFID reader (aka hardware keyboard) while the Delphi XE7 app is running, the app. dies. This reverts the problem back to Embarcadeo once again.